# AWS Website hosting in .NET/SQL - Beginner

Tags: sql, .net, amazon-web-services

Little too late for AWS hosting but I guess its never too late :)

I have a .NET MWC based website hosted on a traditional windows server with SQL server. I have about 5000 hits per day and database of roughly 500 gig in size. Monthly traffic is about 50 GB.

I have to migrate this to AWS, what are the steps? I have a simple .NET C# MVC webapp which connects to SQL server. Also, I would like to know how much will it cost to host website with above mentioned requirements on AWS?

Thanks in Advance
Mandy

Comment: If you are looking for 'opinions', you might get a better response at: https://www.reddit.com/r/aws

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be around $5xx USD per month base on AWS calculator, and $4xx per month for Azure VM + SQL managed Db. If your desire long-term hosting, i will suggest you purchase a proprietary license of SQL server. It will save more!

[For reference : One EC2+One SQL Server](https://calculator.aws/#/estimate?id=40c82e47ed5c270b70eb8153c74685c0c24565ff)

Comment: Oh! Thats expensive! I am better off with $20 a month with hostgator! What makes AWS so expensive??

Comment: @Mandyb Does Hostgator support MS SQL Server? They only seem to list MySQL.

Comment: Yes they do offer MS SQL!

Comment: Intro ultra cheap solution ! Try Heroku Hobby with .net docker and Heroku Postgres dev plan. All together will cost $7 per month if you keep low usage.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using [Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/pricing/), which has a single price for the compute (including Data Transfer), and a single price for the Database (including storage). However, Microsoft SQL Server is not available with Lightsail.

The alternative is to launch:

- An Amazon EC2 instance for your application
- An Amazon RDS database for your SQL Server

The price will vary based upon the size of instance and database you choose. Storage is an extra cost, based on how much you allocate.

Comment: Thanks, I am exploring the same option. Looking at cost mentioned in a reply above I am not really sure..

Comment: Lowest cost Amazon RDS for [SQL Server](https://aws.amazon.com/rds/sqlserver/pricing/) = `db.t3.small` @ `$0.044/hour` = $32/month. For Amazon EC2, an example instance would be `t4g.medium` (2 CPU, 4GB RAM) @ `$0.0336/hour` = $25/month.

Comment: Thanks John. I think should be good to begin with when I decide to migrate.